# How should I use the SCSS variables correctly with the VUE3 stack?

Tags: javascript, sass, vuejs3, vue-cli

In the global file `VUE3` of the project I write the `SCSS` variable.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Further, in one of the modules I try to use it:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
I get an error.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                  17:57:46

 error  in ./src/components/headerNav.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=14455714&lang=scss&scoped=true

Syntax Error: SassError: Undefined variable.
  ╷
6 │   background-color: $--color-second;
  │                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  E:\Progi3\vue3-perfect-goods\src\components\headerNav.vue 6:21  root stylesheet


 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--9-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader
/src??ref--9-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/components/
headerNav.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=14455714&lang=scss&scoped=true 4:14-455 15:3-20:5 16:22-463
 @ ./src/components/headerNav.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=14455714&lang=scss&scoped=true
 @ ./src/components/headerNav.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--15-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--15-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-l
oader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
 @ ./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
 @ ./src/views/Home.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.102:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.ts
```

Question:
Why is this happening and how is it necessary to implement the task in the context of this technology stack? 
P.S. The editor itself picks up the color of the variable correctly: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: I have this same issue, but when removing the scoped from the style tag it works.
But I am expecting the scoped to still get variables from the main App config. Maybe anyone knows this?

Comment: SCSS variables are not CSS variables. While CSS variable definitions cascade down to any DOM descendants of the element defining the variable, SCSS variables are only used at compile time and are only available in current script's (`<style>` tag) context. Shared variables should be placed in a separate file and then loaded anywhere with [`@use`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use scss variables in one scss file from another scss file you usually `@import` or `@use` this file explicitly. This is how scss works. In the case of SFC with `<style>` the scoping part of this logic works as well: to access outer variables we need to import (or use) the .scss file in which they have been declared.

You can though make some stylesheets globally accessible for `<style>` part in all your .vue files using the root config. In Vue 3 it could look like this (from [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders)):

```
css: {
   loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
         additionalData: `@import "./path/to/_variables.scss";`
      }
   }
}
```